# How to copy a scatterplot size scale from another scatterplot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am plotting 2 scatterplots on the same figure and want the dot size to be a function of a certain column. Both scatterplots have same column in question, but when I plot the second scatterplot, the points aren't following the same scale as the first one, as they have different numbers/different sample sizes. Is there any way I could copy the size scale from the first scatterplot and set that as the scale for my second satterplot?

For example, a point with `s=df.column * 2` on the first scatterplot is a different size than the same on the second scatterplot due to the different scales.

Comment: Looks like you need to normalize both sizes columns. Can't go further without sample data?

Comment: In all honesty, the first scatterplot is just my entire sample colored gray. The second scatterplot is one specific scatterpoint (depending on user input) that is colored, since I'm not sure how I would color the one specific scatterpoint in one plot.